# Display text from listview column to different textboxes

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Here's my code

```
Module Module1
Public Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public sql As String

Public Function Connection()
    Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Database1.mdb"
    Conn.Open()
End Function
```

Load my data to the ListView

```
Private Sub ApplicationDesignForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Connection()
    sql = "Select * From App"
    rs.Open(sql, Conn)
    While Not rs.EOF
        Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(rs.Fields("QRCode").Value)
        item.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("Category").Value)
        item.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("LastName").Value & ", " & rs.Fields("FirstName").Value & ", " & rs.Fields("MI").Value)
        item.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("Gender").Value)
        item.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("Address").Value)
            ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
            rs.MoveNext()
    End While
    Conn.Close()
```

Transfer my data to text boxes.

```
If Not ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        txtqrCode.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).Text
        cbCategory.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(1).Text
        txtFirstName.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(2).Text
        cbGender.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(3).Text
        txtAddress.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(4).Text
```

But the problem is the Full Name is only in the First Name Textbox, and not separated by LastName, FirstName and Middle Initial textboxes. I'm stuck and want to separate the LastName, FirstName and MiddeInitial. Greatly appreciated any suggestions or advice.
[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC2hD.jpg)

Comment: When you added the data to the LV, you concatenated First and Last.  The control cant undo what you did.  A DataGridView is a better choice for DB opsl the require less code and have better data typing.

Comment: Actually sir. Our instructor only allow us to use LV and in a hardcoded way.  I couldn't think other solutions to.

Comment: Can you suggest other solution(s) sir. I'm stuck and couldn't think better solution.

Comment: I think you need a smarter teacher or a more up to date course: ADODB and a ListView?  Since you glued the names together, you can use `String.Split` to break them apart

Comment: I think I need smarter teacher. Yes, he only allow us to use ADODB and a ListView. Theres some other operations but he stick with it. But, thank you for your quick response sir. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd check see if initials exist and skip the extra comma if it doesn't

```
If rs.Fields("MI").Value & "" <> "" then
        item.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("LastName").Value & ", " & rs.Fields("FirstName").Value & ", " & rs.Fields("MI").Value)
else
        item.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("LastName").Value & ", " & rs.Fields("FirstName").Value)
end if
```

Then you CAN break apart the full name appropriately

```
  ' I'd use an intermediate variable here, just so you can see what is happening while debugging.
  Dim FullName as string = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(2).Text
  Dim NMA() As String = Split(FullName, ", ", 3)
  Redim Preserve NMA(2) '<--- make sure we have three parts
  txtLastName.text = NMA(0)
  txtFirstName.text = NMA(1)
  txtInitials.text = NMA(2)
```

**NOTE:** The ,3 in the split function limits the split to three items. This may seem unimportant, however, there is no Guarantee some user will not add ", " somewhere in the name fields... e.g. "Charles, The 3rd" in the first name.. Using the length limiter ensures whatever is left after the second ", " gets plonked into the initials field.

I'd also improve the efficiency a bit by using a **With block** in there....

```
With ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0))
    ....
    Dim FullName as string = .SubItems(2).Text
    ....
End With
```

**HOWEVER:** There is an issue with breaking apart the string... the last name could have ", " contained within it. As such your textboxes **may not contain the correct database values** using this method.

For that reason, you are better to fetch the values from somewhere else. Either directly from the database again, or better, store them into some other list type structure when you read the database.

Something like...

```
Private QR_Records As New List(Of QR_REcord)
Private Structure QR_Record
    Public Code As String
    Public Category As String
    Public Name_Last As String
    Public Name_First As String
    Public Name_Initials As String
    'etc

    Public ReadOnly Property Name_Full() As String
        Get
            If Name_Initials.Length > 0 Then
                Return (Name_Last & ", " & Name_First & ", " & Name_Initials)
            Else
                Return (Name_Last & ", " & Name_First)
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Structure
```

Then build that from your database reader function and reference it from the selected list index directly.

```
With QR_Records(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0))
    ....
    Dim FullName as string = .Name_Full
    ....
End With
```

**BONUS:** The added benefit of using this method is that you can use the ListView in **[VIRTUAL MODE](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42229/Virtual-Mode-ListView)** which will give you MUCH MUCH better performance when there are a large number of records.

For that reason I would actually make the ListViewItem a property of the QR_Record as follows

```
Public ReadOnly Property List_Item() as ListViewItem
    Get
        Dim Item As new ListViewItem
        Item.Text = Code
        item.SubItems.Add(Category)
        item.SubItems.Add(Name_Full)
        ....
        Return Item
    End Get
End Property
```

**Having said all that:** As others have pointed out... This really is not the right approach to the problem in it's entirety.